# C++ - Clear array of pointers stored in two places

Tags: c++11, vector

In a constructor for a class `Block` i push the created instance into a static vector `static std::vector<Block*> allBlocks`, and remove them in the destructor.

This works if i just create blocks without pointers, ie. `Block b;`

However, want to have another class return a `std::vector<Block*> grid` for use, which creates them and adds them into the `allBlocks` vector also. Destroying the `grid` vector doesn't seem to run their destructors.

I've tried:
`grid.clear()` using `erase/remove` and just `pop_back`

What would be a better way to store/return them so that when the `grid` is destroyed, so will the contained `Blocks`.

Comment: And what is your question? This is the correct behaviour; neither vector has owning references so neither vector's destructor will call Blocks destructors.

Comment: Trying to find a better way to store/return them so the destructors will be called.

Comment: And what about the pointers in `allBlocks` that will point to now dead blocks destroyed by `grid` destruction? Do you want reference counting and shared ownership here?

Comment: As a side note, this static vector sounds like an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: Their destructors remove them from `allBlocks`. I'm not versed in c++ at all so i'm just trying to teach myself here, if there is a better way (im sure there is), i'm open to suggestions

Comment: I don't think you want this `std::vector<Block*> allBlocks` at all. And don't use pointers either. `std::vector<Block> grid` will let you `push_back` or `emplace` all the extra blocks you want, when `grid` goes out of scope, so will all the `Blocks`. If you really need dynamically allocated `Blocks` use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Block>> grid` again, when the `grid` goes out of scope, so will the `std::unique_ptr<Block>` which wall call the destructor to delete the blocks from the free store.

Comment: I recommend you look up the concepts of 'ownership' and 'value semantics'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so if you want a really better way, a couple of changes:

- No `static`s! They aren't necessary at all here.
- If, as you've stated, you want two containers containing those objects *but in such a way that removing one object removes them from every other container*, it becomes more problematic.

First, it's impossible for one container to remove elements from another unless it has a reference to it in a way. You could create a variable that would hold all of the containers of your blocks and use *that* to remove the block from every container, but... yeah.

In this case, a weak reference solution is acceptable, as long as you remember about the implications.

### `std::shared_ptr` ownership and `std::weak_ptr` reference

Create an `std::set<shared_ptr<Block>> blocks;`, then two containers with weak references; might be called `allBlocks` or `grid` or whatever. Those weak references collection could be for example `std::set<std::weak_ptr<Block>>`.

Now when removing an element from the `grid` or `allBlocks`, you need to remove it from the `blocks`. To do the lookup on it, you'd need something like this:

```
struct null_deleter {
    void operator()(void const *) const { }
};
```

To properly create a value for the set lookup. Then, when iterating over any other container, you'd need to use `ptr.expired()` on the `weak_ptr` reference in order to see if it was deleted previously.

The caveat of that idea is that the original `shared_ptr` isn't *shared*; the class is used just for convenience of `weak_ptr` and automatic destruction.

### `std::unique_ptr` ownership and `int` reference

Another, perhaps simpler way is to use `std::unordered_map` and create a "unique ID" key for each block.

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::unique_ptr<Block>> blocks;
```

Now your containers need to be `std::set<unsigned>`, and the lookup would look like:

```
for (auto b : grid) {
    auto bIt = blocks.find(b);
    if (bIt != blocks.end) {
        // do things with *bIt
    } else {
        // e.g. add the b to the "delete list"
    }
}
```

Now you could process your "delete list" and remove the dead ids from the container.

### Wrapping up

Since this might get tedious to use, a nice idea could be to wrap the `set` into a container that would do the cleanup before returning `begin()` or `end()` for custom iteration across Block values.

Similarly, the destructor of such wrapped structure could remove the values from the map, thus effectively making all ids in all other containers dangling.

This of course raises an issue of thread safety, because the original `blocks` map would need to be locked for the whole iteration; at least for modification. Having `cbegin()/cend()` could allow two threads to read from the same shared `map`, but ... The kind of problems that arise when sharing data across threads are out of scope for this post, though.

### Poisoning

Another idea that came to my mind is sometimes referred to as "poisoning". In this case, you don't need a master container; both of your regular containers would hold `shared_ptr`s to the Blocks... with a twist.

When a Block is chosen for deletion, a special flag is set on it. It becomes "poisoned", and every container should sweep such blocks before doing iteration.

If every container indeed does so, all references to the Block die and its destructor will fire properly. You're essentially communicating the command through a special value of it.

If you don't want to modify the Block class, having `std::shared_ptr<std::optional<Block>>` and nullyfying the `optional` can work just the same, except the destructor of the Block will run immediately, and not when the last structure decides to do its sweep. This might be better or worse depending on your goals and needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try my hand at this.

Comment: @EvanWard I've came up with another idea and added it at the bottom. It's a bit simpler than others, so you might want to try that out as well.